# How can I generate a report that shows me my slowest running tests in Rails 3.2, Ruby 1.9?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest, shoulda

I know that RSpec has the --profile option, but I'm only using MiniTest/shoulda for my current project.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [minitest-reporters](https://github.com/kern/minitest-reporters) for this purpose. This gem provide multiple reporters to see output of your tests.

```
Minitest::Reporters.use! Minitest::Reporters::SpecReporter.new
```

Spec reporter shows the time which each test take to run. It shows the time on console, not as a report.

Answer (score 9):

You can just use:

```
rake TESTOPTS="-v"
```

right out of the box. eg:

```
rake TESTOPTS="-v" test:controllers
```

I have tested this with Ruby 1.9.3 on Rails 3.2.