# Ruby on Rails: how to find the slowest tests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, minitest

I'm writing tests using the default Rails testing framework. Is there a way to find which tests are the slowest?

Answer (score 3):

How about [minitest-reporters](https://github.com/kern/minitest-reporters), as suggested here:

[How can I generate a report that shows me my slowest running tests in Rails 3.2, Ruby 1.9?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23620763/how-can-i-generate-a-report-that-shows-me-my-slowest-running-tests-in-rails-3-2)

It's Rails 4-compatible, and the Installation and Usage sections on GitHub show how to configure the SpecReporter option.

Answer (score 2):

With [Rails 7.1](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/49082) you can now do

```
rails test --profile
```